# Search for string with wildcard in file python

Tags: python, string, wildcard

Basically what I am trying to do is check what strings a file (File1) is missing when comparing it to another (template.file). Once I have this I will append the File1 with the missing string.

**File1 content:**

> dn_name:
>
> ip_addr: 10.0.0.0

**template.file content:**

> dn_name:
>
> ip_addr:

My approach:

```
f = open("template.file", "r")
t = open("File1").read()

for line in f:
        if line in t:
                print "found" + 'line'
        else:
                print "Not found"
```

The problem with this is , in my example the script will only print found for dn_name: but not for ip_addr: since it has the IP as well. 
I Basically need something like

```
if line* in t:
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You are asking your program to find `ip_addr: 10.0.0.1` inside the file that contains only `ip_addr:`. Therefore, it does not find it. Perhaps you meant to swap `f` and `t` in your code, or did you want a two way matching?

Comment: Whatever I got from your description, compare keys rather than line for e.g split lines using : and compare key and append if any key is missing

Comment: @BasJansen I made a mistake with my file content.

Comment: @BasJansen no , My mistake was in my question above. Have a look at my question now and you will see I swapped where the ip addr 10.0.0.0 is but I am still having the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the new line character, specifically you were searching for `ip_addr:\n` inside the template file which is not in there (as the program was correctly telling you). Therefore, to achieve what you want you have to chomp the newline char away using `rstrip()` as I did below:

```
f = open("template.file", "r")
t = open("File1").read()

for line in f:
    if line.rstrip() in t:
        print "found " + line
    else:
        print line + " Not found"
```

Furthermore, there is no `*` in python, the `in` operator already does exactly what you wanted.

Lastly, if you want to do a lot of comparisons then I would suggest the use of a `set`.